# Postgres seems to be using the wrong index?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres 9.4. This is my table:

```
                                       Table "public.frontend_prescription"
      Column       |          Type           |                             Modifiers
-------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 id                | integer                 | not null default nextval('frontend_prescription_id_seq'::regclass)
 presentation_code | character varying(15)   | not null
 total_items       | integer                 | not null
 processing_date   | date                    | not null
 practice_id       | character varying(6)    | not null
Indexes:
    "frontend_prescription_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "frontend_prescription_6ea07fe3" btree (practice_id)
    "frontend_prescription_by_practice" btree (presentation_code, practice_id)
    "frontend_prescription_by_practice_and_code" btree (practice_id, presentation_code varchar_pattern_ops)
    "frontend_prescription_idx_date_and_code" btree (processing_date, presentation_code)
```

This is my query:

```
EXPLAIN (analyse, verbose) 
SELECT SUM(total_items) AS items, SUM(total_items) AS numerator 
FROM frontend_prescription 
WHERE ((presentation_code LIKE '0601012Z0%') OR (presentation_code LIKE '0601012X0%') OR (presentation_code LIKE '0601012V0%'))  
AND (practice_id='A81001')  
AND (processing_date='2016-01-01')
```

This is the output:

```
 Aggregate  (cost=12.26..12.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=16898.277..16898.277 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: sum(total_items), sum(total_items)
   ->  Index Scan using frontend_prescription_idx_date_and_code on public.frontend_prescription  (cost=0.57..12.26 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=9220.091..16898.251 rows=6 loops=1)
         Output: id, presentation_code, presentation_name, total_items, net_cost, actual_cost, quantity, processing_date, price_per_unit, chemical_id, pct_id, practice_id, sha_id
         Index Cond: (frontend_prescription.processing_date = '2016-01-01'::date)
         Filter: (((frontend_prescription.practice_id)::text = 'A81001'::text) AND (((frontend_prescription.presentation_code)::text ~~ '0601012Z0%'::text) OR ((frontend_prescription.presentation_code)::text ~~ '0601012X0%'::text) OR ((frontend_prescription.presentation_code)::text ~~ '0601012V0%'::text)))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 10036400
 Planning time: 6.054 ms
 Execution time: 16898.366 ms
```

Here is the [link to the explain](https://explain.depesz.com/s/4WZ1).

Could anyone suggest how I might speed these queries up? I don't really understand why Postgres is using the `frontend_prescription_idx_date_and_code` index, when the `frontend_prescription_by_practice_and_code` index has a varchar option which should make things faster.

Perhaps it would help if I made a three-column index?

Comment: You want an index on all three columns (date, practice_id, code).

Comment: You could maybe also speed this up by adding a range on code: `AND presentation_code between '0601012' and '0601013'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT SUM(total_items) AS items, SUM(total_items) AS numerator 
FROM frontend_prescription 
WHERE ((presentation_code LIKE '0601012Z0%') OR (presentation_code LIKE '0601012X0%') OR (presentation_code LIKE '0601012V0%')
       ) AND
       (practice_id = 'A81001')  AND
       (processing_date = '2016-01-01');
```

The best index is a composite index on `frontend_prescription(practice_id, processing_date, presentation_code, total_items)`.   The last column is not strictly necessary.  It makes the index a covering index for the query; in other words, all the information needed for the query is in the index, so the data pages are not necessary.

The first two columns can be in either order because the `where` clause uses equality.

Comment: thanks very much! Given that I have a `LIKE` query, would it make sense to use `varchar_ops`, so `create index myindex on frontend_prescription(practice_id, processing_date, presentation_code varchar_pattern_ops, total_items)`?